# Insert data in data grid in vb.net from database

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to retrieve data from the database. I can connect to the database and retrieve the data but when I try and put it into a data grid I get an error saying

> index out of range exception was unhandled ORDERDETAILS.PRODUCTID.

The SQL statement works but not sure about the code for inputting it into a data grid. any help would be appreciated.

```
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=msdaora;Data Source=orabis;User Id=112221739;Password=112221739;"

    conn.Open()


    Dim work As Integer
    work = CInt(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand


    cmd = conn.CreateCommand()


    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT     ORDERDETAILS.PRODUCTID,PRODUCTS.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION,ORDERDETAILS.ORDERQUANTITY,ORDERDETAILS. ORDERQUANTITYTOTAL FROM CUSTOMER, ORDERS, ORDERDETAILS, PRODUCTS  WHERE CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = ? AND CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = ORDERS.CUSTOMERID AND ORDERS.ORDERID = ORDERDETAILS.ORDERID AND ORDERDETAILS.PRODUCTID = PRODUCTS.PRODUCTID"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", work)
    Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If dr.HasRows Then
          DataGridView1.Rows.Add(CInt(dr.Item("ORDERDETAILS.PRODUCTID")),        CStr(dr.Item("PRODUCTS.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION")), CInt(dr.Item("ORDERDETAILS.ORDERQUANTITY")), CInt(dr.Item("ORDERDETAILS.ORDERQUANTITYTOTAL")))
    End If
    dr.Close()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read from the datareader before grabbing values.

```
If dr.Read Then
      DataGridView1.Rows.Add(CInt(dr.Item("ORDERDETAILS.PRODUCTID")),        CStr(dr.Item("PRODUCTS.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION")), CInt(dr.Item("ORDERDETAILS.ORDERQUANTITY")), CInt(dr.Item("ORDERDETAILS.ORDERQUANTITYTOTAL")))
End If
```

Comment: What would be the full code for this..?? should I put dr.read in place of dr.HasRows..?? Sorry for taking so long to respond. this is part of a college project and only had the chance to long at it again now :-)